# Excel VBA - Best way to pause procedural code while waiting for asynchronous operation

Tags: excel, vba, asynchronous

I'm working with some external Excel VBA libraries that perform asynchronous operations, and I'm wondering if there's a way of pausing code execution until some event has fired (as an alternative to just busy-waiting, which is what I'm currently doing)

Say you've got two class modules, `AsyncClassModule`

```
Public Event ExampleEvent()

Public Sub DoSomethingAsynchronous()
    'Some operation would run here, then fire the event when complete
    'In the real case I'm working with, this is an external library I can't control
    RaiseEvent ExampleEvent
End Sub
```

And `CallerClassModule`

```
Private WithEvents x As AsyncClassModule

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set x = New AsyncClassModule
    
    x.DoSomethingAsynchronous
    
    'This is the issue; need to somehow wait for asynchronous operation to complete before proceeding
    
    MsgBox "All done!"
End Sub
```

What I'd like to do is, after calling `DoSomethingAsynchronous`, pause code execution until `ExampleEvent` has fired. Currently, I'm just busy-waiting, like this:

```
Private WithEvents x As AsyncClassModule
Private asyncOperationComplete As Boolean

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set x = New AsyncClassModule
    
    asyncOperationComplete = False
    x.DoSomethingAsynchronous
    
    While Not asyncOperationComplete
        DoEvents
        Sleep 1000
    Wend
    
    MsgBox "All done!"
End Sub

Private Sub x_ExampleEvent()
    asyncOperationComplete = True
End Sub
```

Are there any alternatives to looping in this situation, which won't take up CPU time while waiting? In pseudo-code, ideally I'd like something like this:

```
x.DoSomethingAsynchronous
Pause until x.ExampleEvent fires
MsgBox "All done!"
```

Comment: I think the external libraries should provide the methods to do this. E.g. a blocking call to start the async processing (so now it is sync), or a non-blocking call taking the address of an event handler.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie They do provide blocking calls, but in my case I need to update a userform showing log output from the asynchronous operation while it's running (the asynchronous operation can take several minutes). There's no option to stream the log output either, it needs to be continually called like `x.fetchLogOutput`

Comment: You could start a 2nd instance of Excel which loads a workbook with an AutoStart macro that starts the library, then use your first instance to poll the log.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie To even further complicate things, the external library provides a different event that fires when intermediate steps have completed, which I'm using to know when log updates need to be fetched (which neatly avoids having to loop while waiting for log output). So, the log polling needs to use the same class instance as the main async operation.

Comment: So you have blocking call of the library, which fires an event at some intervals. Then do your processing in the event handler (an event is only an event if an event handler is called and if the event handler can be provided by the caller/user)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Shoot, you're right. I'd tried a similar solution as my first attempt, and ran into issues, so I just mentally discarded it (the debugger isn't very helpful when working with async stuff). Turns out I'd just had some unrelated bugs in my code; going back and redoing it as you said worked perfectly. Thanks!